# Different Pylint Standards for Test Files

Tags: python, pytest, pylint

I have a typical Python codebase with hundreds of `.py` files in dozens of directories, and dozens of `/tests/` directories filled with `test_whatever.py` files (that I run using `pytest`).

But, honestly, I have a much lower bar for caring about `pylint` things in test files than in real code. How do I ignore these four things for files in `/tests/` folders?

1. `missing-module-docstring`
2. `missing-class-docstring`
3. `missing-function-docstring`
4. `protected-access`

The only one I've managed to *mostly* solve is the function docstring one, by putting this in my `pylintrc`:

```
no-docstring-rgx=^_|^test_
```

Is it possible to fix the others? (I cannot fully exclude test files from linting.)

Comment: how do you run pylint ? are you using tox for example ? what I usually do is adding to executions of pylint in tox, one for code and one for tests and this way I can send different args between the two

Comment: Personally I'm using pre-commit which has an exclude option that permit to filter ``test/``

Comment: @ozs Yeah, pylint is usually run by tox. Can you show how that works? I'd love to see it!

Answer (score 1):

Is anything wrong with splitting up pylint for prodcode dir and test dir?

```
    [testenv:pylint-prodcode]
    deps = -r {toxinidir}/requirements.txt
    commands =
        python -m pylint --rcfile=pylintrc --ignore-paths=prodcode/tests prodcode
        python -m pylint --rcfile=pylintrc --disable=missing-function-docstring,missing-class-docstring,unused-argument,missing-module-docstring prodcode/tests
```

It works great, but I can't find another solution with this approach so I am a bit uncertain? The only disadvantage is that the test time slightly increased by a few seconds.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Well, the code base I was thinking of has ~a hundred different `tests/` directories. So, I wouldn't want to have to configure those all manually on that command line. People might add/remove test dirs on the fly, and that would mean they would have to KNOW to come to this line and modify the very long config.

Still, for simple/small projects, this is probably doable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use tox which is a generic virtualenv management and test command line tool.
tox helps you :

- checking that your package installs correctly in different python versions
- running your tests in each of the environments
- acting as a frontend to Continuous Integration servers

you can read more about tox in their official [website](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

install tox with `pip install tox`

add tox.ini file on the root level. see project structure in the image below

[image]

in the tox.ini a basic configuration to run tests and pylint would be like this:

```
[tox]
minversion = 2.0
envlist = py36, pylint
skipsdist = True

[testenv]
commands = {envbindir}/pytest {posargs}
deps = -r{toxinidir}/requirements.txt
       -r{toxinidir}/dev-requirements.txt
recreate = False
passenv = *

[testenv:pylint]
basepython=python3.6
deps = -r{toxinidir}/requirements.txt
       -r{toxinidir}/dev-requirements.txt
commands=pylint src
         pylint --disable=missing-module-docstring,missing-class-docstring tests
```

as you can see, I split pylint to 2 commands which let me control how to lint my *src* and *tests* differently.

to run tox (tests + lint) just run `tox` in the terminal from tox.ini directory.

if you would like only to run pylint then you can run `tox -e pylint`

Comment: Darn.  So problem is somewhat more complicated. (1) `/tests/` is inside `/src/`, and second, I have dozens of `/tests/` folders at different levels of depth. hmm

Comment: you can create 2 pylintrc files (for each command). 
in the pylintrc you can use "ignore-patterns" to define the blacklist files.
run pylint --rcfile=path , one for src and one for tests